# What function is called whenever a UIPageViewController is swiped?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I need to execute another function whenever an UIPageView is swiped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conform to [`UIPageViewControllerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontrollerdelegate) and implement the following methods:

```
func pageViewController(UIPageViewController, willTransitionTo: [UIViewController]) {
    // called when swiping begins
}

func pageViewController(UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted: Bool) {
    // called when swiping ends
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [UIPageViewControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontrollerdelegate). You are probably looking for `pageViewController(_:didFinishAnimating:previousViewControllers:transitionCompleted:)`